# Alternative operators to NOT LIKE in PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas

For example:

```
proc sql;
     create table Names as
     select Firstname
     from Persons
     where Firstname not like "M%"

quit;
```

I selected all Firstnames that do not start with letter M, but is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example:

```
    proc sql;
         create table Names as
         select Firstname
         from Persons
         where substr(Firstname,1,1) ne "M";
    quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
where firstname < 'M' or firstname >= 'N'
```

However, I think `not like` is clearer in intent.

Answer (score 0):

**May be below code help you:-**

```
proc sql;
     create table Names as
     select Firstname
     from Persons
     where left(Firstname,1)<>'M'

quit;
```